# Debugging using Nvidia Nsight 2.2 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: cuda, gpu, nsight

I am using  Dell Precision T3500 workstation with Quadro 2000 Nvidia GPU. I installed Cuda 4.2 tool kit with Nsight 2.2. When I debug cuda code using "Start CUDA Debugging" it connect the local machine then just gives a message

> A CUDA context was created on a GPU that is not debuggable. Breakpoints will be disabled.  Adapter: Quadro 2000

and exit.

Is there any issue with VS project settings or Cuda configuration.

I also tried CUDA 5.0 without any use.

Comment: It could be releated to the driver you are using. What's your Nsight build number (check from menu Nsight\Help\About Nsight), and the driver version? That could be helpful to get a solution for your issue. Basically, it would be functional with the recommeneded driver version by that Nsight version.

Comment: I am using nsight 2.2.01225 and graphic driver is 306.95 . Nsight 2.2 download page says it works well with drivers 301.27 or newer. I also tried cuda 5 . But still get same message :(

Comment: Nsight 2.2 does not officially support Cuda 5.0. And the driver 306.x features Kepler and Cuda 5.0, but with that Nsight 2.2 does not work as perfect as 301.42 <the one recommended>.  FYI, there will be a preview release of Nsight in coming weeks with Cuda 5.0 support.

Comment: I tired installing nsight recomemeded drivers and tool kit. Now i dont get that error but in the same time it dont stop on any of the break points in device code. Any hint?

Comment: Please double check whether the CUDA code is compiled with tk 4.2 but not the Cuda5.0. If problem presists, you can try a sample from the samples in Cuda SDK. If still not working, you can send email to parallelNsight-support@nvidia.com, people will assit you in detail.

Comment: Yes still facing same problem. I will contact nsight team ans update here. Thank you xuan

Comment: I tied to VS 2010 Premium on a system, right now I'll try to use CUDA 5.5.2 and NSight 3.2.2.

Answer (score -3):

It's possible that the current driver version and nsight version are not compatible with the PC hardware. The following worked for me:

1. Download the latest CUDA TOOLKIT (current is 7.5).
2. Reload the CUDA.
3. Do not update the driver.